# Memory issue after upgrading Unity engine from 3.5.5 to 4.1.2

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are suddenly having memory problem after we upgraded Unity engine from 3.5.5 to 4.1.2.  We did not make changes in options and pretty much replaced the engine for our existing app, but somehow the memory usage increased by 90M.  It worked just fine with previous version.  Did we miss something? Is this a known problem?

Comment: You might want to share a little more information about your app.

Comment: In this form it's going to be impossible to answer. What version of Unity are you on? Pro? If so, run the profiler and see if you can get an idea of what is taking your memory.

Comment: It also could be that unity 4 is more ram heavy than unity 3. They did change a lot between the versions of unity, including adding stuff like more complex animation systems